# Reloading fragment leaves blank screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

I added fragment in framelayout in following way

```
    mUserListFragment = new UserListFragment();
    mMessageFragment = new MessageFragment();
    mAccountFragment = new AccountFragment();

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_layout, mAccountFragment, mAccountFragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(mAccountFragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_layout, mMessageFragment, mMessageFragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(mMessageFragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_layout, mUserListFragment, mUserListFragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(mUserListFragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
```

Later I display or hide fragment in following way

```
//for showing
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragment).commit();

//for hiding 
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragment).commit();
```

From one of the fragment I go to another Activity, Via some onClick method  , and that Activity redirect to the same activity which was holding the fragments . When it comes back to the fragment holder activity , I reload the fragment in `onResume` , but it makes that fragment blank , however by debugging I came to know that , fragment is visible and `onCreateView` method was called , I tried to reload fragment in following way

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

ft.setReorderingAllowed(false);

ft.detach(activeFragment).commitNow();
ft.attach(activeFragment).commitNow();
```

Also I tried this

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(activeFragment).attach(activeFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

All of those just leave blank screen.

Comment: did you tried `FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().AddToBackStack`

Comment: Yes I did try so . But no luck

Comment: can You post some code regarding activity navigation?

Comment: did you check if your fragments are not null before you try to show/hide them? eg by `FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag`

Comment: @K.Dexter yes I checked it is not null .

Answer (score 0):

You can track fragment's stack and count of fragments by below code.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                Log.i(TAG, "back stack changed ");
                int backCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

                // you can also track which are current fragments are in stack by
                getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();

                if(backCount ==0){

                    //then you have to check whats going wrong in your case
                    // suppose to kill current activity also by finish();
                    // I means its depending on your requirements.


                }

            }
        });
```

It will help you to find your way.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create your Fragment via newInstanse() method.

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    public static YourFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

In Activity:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
  .beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.content,YourLoanFragment.newInstance(),tag)
  .commit();
```